# pdflatex: Appendix section number is wrong

Tags: tex

The appendix section number is wrong. The whole project is at:
https://github.com/JerryOpenix/Debugging-With-GDB

MWE is below:
The section number of Appendix B is wrong.

Don't tell me to set the section number of Appendix B to be 0 at the start manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{book}

\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\appendix

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\alph{chapter}}
\chapter*{Appendix A Installing GDB}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Installing GDB}

\section*{tools to build gdb}
\#TODO

\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{call configuration script}
\#TODO

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{B\alph{chapter}}
\chapter*{Appendix B GDB protocol}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{GDB protocol}

\section{Overview}
\#TODO

\cleardoublepage
\end{document}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is somewhat contrived (and I wasn't going to dive into compiling an entire project from GitHub). Here's the gist of what's happening:

You're using `\chapter*` to represent every appendix chapter. The starred version of `\chapter` implies that no counter will be set in the chapter heading. It also implies that the `chapter` counter will not be stepped (increased). The consequence from not stepping the `chapter` counter is that none of the lower-level sectional units have their counters reset. That's why the first section in the second appendix carries on from the first section in the first appendix.

You could attempt to add the following to your preamble:

```
\let\oldappendix\appendix% Store \appendix in \oldappendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{% Update \appendix to...
  \oldappendix           % ...call the traditional \appendix
  \let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{% Update \chapter to...
    \setcounter{section}{0}% ...reset the section counter and...
    \oldchapter% ...call the traditional \chapter macro
  }%
}
```

The above code will update `\appendix` to do what it always does, but also add an update to `\chapter`. This update will reset the `section` counter in case you use `\chapter*`. Even if you were to use `\chapter`, it wouldn't matter.